# CSS - Position absolute is affected by sibling's margins

Tags: html, css, position, css-position, absolute

I have a element which is `absolute` positioned, relative to parent. However, the position is affected by a sibling element which has a vertical margin. Why does the absolutely positioned element, in-spite having property `top` equals zero, start from the same position as the sibling element which has vertical margins on it.

Please see this [Codepen](https://codepen.io/kayote/pen/ExamGxX?editors=1100).

In the codepen above, the element div.b is absolutely positioned, however it is affected by sibling element div.a. The element div.a has vertical margin applied to it.

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="a">
        <div class="childA"></div>
        <div class="childA"></div>
        <div class="childA"></div>
        <div class="childA"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="b"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.parent {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: blue;
}

.a {
    margin: 50px;
}

.childA {
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
}

.b {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: red;
    top: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

This is a bit tricky, but when an element doesn't have any padding, the margins of its children are able to spill out beyond the contents of the container. This is referred to as [collapsing margins](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/box.html#collapsing-margins) and happens regardless of whether or not you're using `position: (relative|absolute)`.

```css
.block {
  height: 50px;
  background: #ccc;
}

.parent {
  background: #900;
}

.child {
  margin: 40px 0;
  background: #600;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="block"></div>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">Child</div>
</div>
<div class="block"></div>
```

Note that the `.parent` does not have a margin or padding, but there is a gap between `.child` and `.block` elements.

Typically when this behavior is undesirable you're better served by padding than margins, which also allows your background fill to continue to the edge of the spacing.

Comment: Thank you for the guidance. I think the issue, or where my knowledge gap was, was that the parent doesn't itself have any height, it expands/ contracts as per the children. In my case above, the first child has a starting point offset by margin top, so that is where the body is starting from. And that is what the 2nd child, the absolutely positioned one, sees as the starting point. Thank you for the solution proposed.

Answer (score 1):

Because, as you said in your question, it is positioned relative to its parent. `relative` positioned elements create a new stacking context for their children. Either move `.b` out of it's parent or remove `position" relative;` from the parent

```css
body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.parent {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: blue;
}

.a {
    margin: 50px;
}

.childA {
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
}

.b {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: red;
    top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <div class="a">
        <div class="childA"></div>
        <div class="childA"></div>
        <div class="childA"></div>
        <div class="childA"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="b"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Makes sense now. Thank you for the clarification.

Comment: @Laif While your explanation of `position: relative` is helpful, I don't think it fully describes the effect Kayote is experiencing here.